# Why does upgrading jQuery break the jQuery UI functionality?

Tags: jquery, css, hover

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/KpEMc/1718/

Everything is perfectly fine with this one. It is JQuery 1.4.4 version. But when I update the JQuery version to the latest one, it does not work. Why?

The updated version can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KpEMc/1719/).

Here is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sample").mouseover(function() {
         $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#f00'},300);
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).animate({ backgroundColor:'#ccc'},300);
    });       
});
```

Comment: Show error thrown in JS console.

Comment: when you update jquery version in fiddle.you have check `jquery UI version` too.Cause it needs to `Jquery UI` to be checked in fiddler.http://jsfiddle.net/KpEMc/1719/

Comment: @SrinivasR is correct. You just didn't set up jsfiddle correctly.

Comment: Running that second fiddle leads to my JS error console being flooded with "Warning: Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped." messages - presumably one for each stage of the colour transition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not selecting jQuery UI. Just tick `jQuery UI 1.9.2`.

Here you go: [**Working jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MyQLs/)

You should also try

```
on("mouseover", function() {} );
```

Comment: Is there a particular benefit you're referring to by using `.on()` in that fashion? If OP was working with dynamic content, you would have an obvious case for using on() and event delegation.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte Just sharing...

Comment: Sounds good, was just curious about your suggestion. :) Nothing wrong with using `.on()`!

Comment: `on` doesn't actually work with dynamic content in the same way `live` did. You can do `$('body').on('click', '.a_class', function(){});`, to ensure `.a_class` works even if added later, but simply doing `$('.a_class').on('click', function(){});` won't work unless `.a_class` is present when `on` is called.

Comment: That's my point, @RichBradshaw. :) OP doesn't need to use event delegation in this case, and can directly register the event handlers because there is no dynamic content in this case.

Comment: But that's what `on` does! From the docs: "This method is a shortcut for .on('mouseover', handler)". http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ .

Comment: @RichBradshaw Yes, I know. I don't think we are in disagreement... OP's use of mouseover/mouseout is the same as doing `.on('mouseover', handler)`, thus, I was curious as to why it was being suggested that he refactor for essentially the same code. Not sure what you think I'm saying... We agree that `.on()` can do both direct and delegated events! lol

Comment: Oh this is not my code, I'm really so new to JQuery and JS stuff. I can just make little changes to them. ^^ so I don't know what 'on' is for. :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really reading in context. :) I thought you were implying there was an overhead in using `.on`, rather than stating that it doesn't actually change anything!

Comment: Berdiya – it's exactly the same, jQuery just provides a few shortcuts. The way you have it is as I'd write it.

Comment: No worries, @RichBradshaw ! :)

Answer (score -2):

My suggestion would be to not use jQuery for something so trivial.

CSS only!

```
#sample {
    background-color:#ccc;
    transition:background-color 0.3s ease;
    -webkit-transition:background-color 0.3s ease;
}
#sample:hover {
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpEMc/1720/)

Comment: -1 No attempt to address the question. Obviously this "trivial" because it is demo code, not production code.

Comment: What about the old browsers?

Comment: If you're using jQuery 2.0, then you already show you don't care about older browsers.

Comment: @BerdiyaOnur If your customers don't have a browser that supports CSS3 then their money is of no value. ;)

Comment: What about IE? `transition` won't work there.

Comment: IE10 supports `transition` just fine, thanks. It's Chrome that's still stuck on using `-webkit-transition`.

Comment: +1 because this addresses the question with the correct solution. "There is a difference between what the asker wants, and what the asker needs" - Anon

Comment: If the question is specifically about jQuery 2 then any talk about "what about OldIE" is irrelevant as the library itself doesn't bother to support them. If you're supporting IE then you're going to be using jQuery 1.9.

Comment: Besides, is it really the end of the world if a background changes to red instead of just fading?

Comment: Chrome 26 and up don't need the `-webkit-` prefix.

Comment: @RichBradshaw True, but that's not the current version.

Comment: Only a few weeks though. Dev is on 27, Beta on 26, Stable on 25.

Comment: Just to clarify my mind, old browsers don't support jQuery 2.0? How come, aren't all versions of jquery developed based on the same version of Javascript? What kind of dramatic change is that? CSS3 is really so new by the way, websites in my opinion should work fine with at least IE7. A couple of years ago, people were worrying about   IE6, they had a point, there were a huge number of people still using it.

Comment: The point of jQuery is the make it easy to support all versions of browsers by doing all the hard work for you. For some bizarre reason, they decided to stop supporting IE7 and below in jQuery 2

Comment: It's not really bizarre – jQuery 1.9 does support these browsers, and has the same features at the moment. It's worth bearing in mind that plenty of other projects have the same support – AngularJS and Bootstrap have simliar browser support. According to StatCounter, in the UK over the last 3 months IE8 had 9%, IE7 had 0.8% and IE6 is too small to appear on their graph. IE8 should have some sort of non broken experience, but lower is irrelevant unless you have a specific knowledge of audience (people who have XP and only upgraded once…)